# Export a copy of the project in Xcode without including the unused files that are inside the project folder

Tags: xcode, optimization, project

It's a long title I know... :P
My problem is this:
I have a Xcode project inside a folder, in this folder there are many files (source code, images, ...) that are not used by the project anymore.
What I would like to do is to export the Xcode project in a different folder getting rid of these files, so that I will have a new folder containing my project and only the files used by the project.
Is it possible?

Thank you.

John

Comment: yes. you can delete that. and you can delete those files from your project hierarchy as well.

Comment: Hinata the files are not on the project hierarchy... that's the point. Ok... I try to explain better:
Suppose you create a project in Xcode called SampleProject. Then Xcode automatically creates a folder called SampleProject. Inside the folder SampleProject there are bunch of files that belong to the project. Consider now if I copy some files inside the SampleProject folder, but these files are not added to the Xcode project. Now I'd like to know if there's a way within Xcode to export the project to another folder considering only the files that are part of the project.

Comment: Do you means extra view controller files ? Which extra files exactly? Every file has an specific part in your project. If you are not using that of course you can delete that.